# Как сделать постоянные повторения при клике?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать постоянные повторения при клике? Действие происходит только один раз:

```
var btnMenu = document.getElementById("menu-btn");

btnMenu.onclick = function() {
  btnMenu.classList.add("menu-btn_active");
  btnMenu.onclick = function() {
    btnMenu.classList.remove("menu-btn_active");
  };
};

//CSS
.menu-btn_active .span-btn:before {
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  width: 10px;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.menu-btn_active .span-btn:after {
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  width: 10px;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var btnMenu = document.getElementById("menu-btn");
btnMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btnMenu.classList.toggle("menu-btn_active");
});
```